# Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-20033 user doesnot change in this schema , ORA-06512

Tags: oracle

I got this error

```
Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-20033 user doesnot change in this schema , ORA-06512
```

in my oracle package.

I run it step by step and it is okey but when I want to compile package it gives this error?
can anyone help me?
thanks.

Comment: Please give an example of the code that is throwing the error

Comment: this error just gives me by sql developer

Comment: Yes it throws the error when you are compiling a piece of code. In order to help you, fix that problem, we need that piece of code that is throwing the error

Comment: @user3086226 please show your code otherwise we may not able to help you

Comment: it is about 3000 lines, 
but it runs step by step , when I compile package it gives this error.

Comment: -1, sorry you are not describing the issue clearly

Comment: I think it s not about code it is about system

Comment: @ling.s hey please read comments

Comment: How do you say its about system. It clearly shows `error occurred at recursive SQL level`

Comment: but it Works yesterday and I did not change any thing but it gives error and I completely delete my code in packages but it gives same error? what about that?

Comment: Post the full error log

Comment: try `alter system set "_system_trig_enabled"=FALSE;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems strange, because ORA-20033 is in the range reserved for user-defined error messages, so you may have code in the database that is preventing the package from compiling.

Your coworkers ought to now what this is, or you could query the DBA_SOURCE table for code that defines and raises this error. A DDL trigger on package creation, possibly.